# setting up sandbox version of pypy

Tags: python, sandbox, pypy

In order to get sandbox version of `Pypy`, first i build `Pypy` from source using this instruction:

```
pypy ../../rpython/bin/rpython -O2 --sandbox targetpypystandalone
```

(Then I rename `Pypy-c` to `Pypy-c-sandbox`)

When i test:

```
./pyinteractive.py
```

It works correctly but when i want to run sandbox version using this command:

```
./pyinteractive.py ../goal/pypy-c-sandbox
```

Following error appears:

```
[platform:execute] gcc -shared /tmp/usession-release-2.5.1-15/module_cache/module_0.o /tmp/usession-release-2.5.1-15/module_cache/module_1.o /tmp/usession-release-2.5.1-15/module_cache/module_2.o /tmp/usession-release-2.5.1-15/module_cache/module_3.o -pthread -Wl,--export-dynamic -lrt -o /tmp/usession-release-2.5.1-15/shared_cache/externmod.so
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes
```

What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: I had a very similar error playing with an earlier version of PyPy's sandbox because I switched from PyPy3 to PyPy2 without realizing it at some point, so ultimately the front end was treating wide Unicode strings as 8-bit strings. I'd say it's unlikely you made the same mistake as me, but if you did, the fix is simple: just trash it and redo it. :)

Comment: The line `./pyinteractive.py ../goal/pypy-c-sandbox` makes no sense; it's like typing `python /usr/bin/python` and getting a SyntaxError.  Where did you find it?

Comment: @ArminRigo in this link [link](http://pypy.org/features.html#sandboxing)

pypy_interact.py path/to/pypy-sandbox
I use this syntax and i think it brings me a sandbox interpreter.

Comment: @ArminRigo I have problem with adding modules (like time, random, ...) to sandbox version, Is there any option to add all (safe) python modules to sandbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misreading the docs: it's not `pyinteractive.py path/to/pypy-sandbox`.  It's `pypy_interact.py path/to/pypy-sandbox` (from pypy/sandbox/).

The modules that work in the sandbox are in a very limited number.  Recently even the `time` module stopped working there, so was removed.  We'd welcome contributions, but more of the kind "continued support", which would include special support for more modules and a better `pypy_interact.py` --- the present one is only there for demo purposes.